# What is the closest bucolic holiday destination to the City of London?

Tags: london, destinations, rural

I have been looking at weekend accommodations in London. For a family with children, this seems quite challenging.

At the same time I am seeing quite some nice bucolic options in Kent and Sussex. To be able to enjoy both London and the countryside, I am wondering what the closest bucolic area to the city ofLondon is and preferably even within the [ceremonial county greater London](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greater_London) .

Sidenote: [Bucolic](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10390/i-am-looking-for-a-hotel-search-engine-for-rural-areas) is a word I learned here.

Comment: That's where I learned that word too! :)

Comment: Perhaps you could describe what sort of bucolic destination you are after? Eg country-side cottage, farm hotel, camping cabins etc.  London also covers a huge area, so has quite a lot of bucolic areas bordering it - maybe you'd prefer a certain side of the compass (eg South London)?

Comment: I don't know if you like camping, but I have used this one http://www.canopyandstars.co.uk/ and I really really love it. it's cottage style accommodation. Some of them are quite close to London e.g Dorset.

Comment: ..Dorset..close to London? 130-odd miles and 2.5 hrs :-)

Comment: @MarkMayo I added more detail to the question. There are tons of rural area's within one hour reach of Greater London. But I am really interested in the rural area's within or pretty close to London

Comment: Also see [Day trips from London](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/5317/108)

Comment: @Andra: in your edit, did you definitely mean to reference the [City of London](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_of_london)? The City isn't where most tourists go (except for maybe St Paul's Cathedral); most of the more famous tourist attractions are in other parts of central London. Hence, "central London" might be a better location to use in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most "bucolic" area very close to central London is Hampstead Heath, which gives a reasonable impression of being out in the countryside once you're away from the perimeter and is certainly big and varied enough for a decent walk. It has reasonably villagey areas with pubs around it near Hampstead Heath station and Highgate, another pub (the Spaniard's Inn) on a road passing through it and a stately home (Kenwood House).

But you can't stay in the middle of the Heath and I think you would be unlikely to find anywhere to stay that wasn't either on a main road in an urbanised area nearby, and/or very expensive. It's always been a day-trip destination. But it's worth a try.

You might also consider Richmond (Richmond Park and the river, trips to Hampton Court). But again I think you'll find accomodation in the most scenic bits sparse or expensive.

Answer (score 1):

London is pretty well-connected by trains to many destinations of-note in the UK, so it's hard to take a pick. However, if you want primarily a rural experience then you have a couple of options:

- **[Windsor and Eton](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Windsor_and_Eton)**: Home of the Windsor Castle and Eton College (famous for being a prestigious school). You need to [book an arranged tour if you want to visit the actual Eton College grounds](http://www.etoncollege.com/PublicOpening.aspx).
- **[Oxford](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Oxford)** and **[Cambridge](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Cambridge_%28England%29)** both make for excellent options for day-trips from London with a relaxed feel. If it's training season, perhaps you can even catch some of the famed Oxbridge rowing teams practising!

Comment: While Oxford and Cambridge surely make for great day trips from London, I wouldn't call them *rural* or *bucolic* exactly...