# Is Legoland Windsor worth visiting, among all the London-area tourist attractions?

Tags: london, children, amusement-parks

We are traveling to London with our kids. As one of the attractions, Legoland Windsor is mentioned. I am wondering if this is more a small/local attraction, or is it a valid attraction to consider when visiting London as a tourist. 
How does it compare to (for example) Disneyland Paris?

We will be traveling with our own car and I am aware of the distance to the city. What I am trying to find out is how special Legoland Windsor is. Is it more aiming at locals as just any other (dime a dozen) amusement park, or would Lego lovers from all over the world be excited?

Comment: The number of tourists (from abroad) who are based in London for their UK stay & visit probably exceeds the "locals" as you put it.Its depends on your definition of "a local" I guess.  In terms of an amusement park we have quite a few you can visit on our island, Legoland Windsor i'm guessing is probably similar to the one in Denmark (which I havent visited) http://www.legoland.dk/en/

Comment: Also the town of Windsor & Windsor Castle is well worth the visit if you have never been. So you may aswell see them all in one go, and as stated in my answer is easy to get to, whether you travel in your own car or not.

Comment: Your edit asking about 'how special' it is, is quite subjective, however I can tell you that I have several NZ friends who have visited it (adults and kids) and loved it - big lego fans!

Comment: @MarkMayo That is what I wanted to know. On Youtube it looks like just your average theme park, not worth traveling long distance for. I am booking tickets now.

Comment: @Andra Windsor is not a long distance from London, & is well worth the visit

Comment: Would the word "intended" be more objective than "considered"?

Comment: Your question boils down to "Is it worth visiting?" (somewhat subjective) and "How much time/money does it take a family to go there (compared to other attractions)?" (more objective). This all depends on how many days you have, your kids ages and interests, etc. Personally I loved it, I'm an adult who was into Lego as a kid. Similar things: The Victoria & Albert Museum, Cutty Sark, Greenwich Meridian, British Museum, etc.

Answer (score 11):

Legoland Windsor is located approximately 20 miles west of Central London. Whether or not you consider that to be a tourist attraction **of London** is entirely up to you. However it proves to be very popular and is easy to get to for the thousands of "London" tourists , as is the town of Windsor & the Royal residence of Windsor Castle (as far as tourist attractions go) as there are frequent buses running several times a day between Windsor - London (of which there are a number of pick up points, where you can hop on and pay the driver) & vice versa with Greenline buses.

More info regarding this bus service can be found here:

http://www.greenline.co.uk/

I don't think it is a comparison to be made with Disneyland Paris, as I would consider Legoland Windsor to be a one day affair only. But an enjoyable one at that.

Answer (score 10):

It is very common to do [day trips from London](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/5344/449) to Windsor Castle The difference between the castle and Legoland on public transport is a 15 min bus (see below for reference and details).

Is it a London Attraction? Well that depends on how you measure London.

**London**

Technically London is the [city of London](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_of_London) (the square mile)

**Greater London Area**

[The Greater London Area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greater_London) 32 boroughs plus the city. The GLA transport is controlled by [Transport for London](http://www.tfl.gov.uk/) (TFL) This means all areas inside the GLA are in the Oyster zones however there are several areas in the zones outside GLA. This is important form a ticketing perspective.

**Inside the M25**

The [M25](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M25_motorway) is an orbital road ( encompasses the greater London Area  however not all town inside the M25 are not part of London an example of this is [Staines-Upon-Thames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staines), which is in the borough of Spelthrone, which is in the county of Surrey )

**Precedent for things outside of GLA being called London**

There are a number of [airports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_airports) in the united kingdom that have London in their name that are not in the Greater London Area the furthest from the centre of London  is [London Southend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_Southend_Airport) at 36 miles in the county of Essex. All of the international airports with London in their names (London City, London Gatwick, London Heathrow, London Luton, London Southend, and London Stansted) are all connected via rail to major London Train stations.

So is Legoland in Windsor a London tourist attraction?

- Inside the city of London: N
- Inside the GLA: N
- Inside the M25: N
- Closer than other places with London in their names: Y

I would say it is dubious to call Legoland London.

However that doesn't mean it is hard to get there from London. Windsor and Eton Riverside is 53 min from Waterloo on a direct train. Windsor and Eton Central is between 26 and 36 min from Paddington changing in Slough. Then a [15 min](http://www.firstgroup.com/ukbus/berkshire_thames/assets/pdfs/journey_planning/shuttletimetable.pdf) [Bus](http://www.firstgroup.com/ukbus/berkshire_thames/journey_planning/legoland_shuttle/) ride (the stop is roughly halfway between both stations.)

The [Legoland Website](http://www.legoland.co.uk/Plan/Directions/) has a full set of directions.

Note that Windsor is not covered by TFL Travel Card zones.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up visiting Legoland Windsor with my kids. I can only say that it was worth every penny, even with the freezing temperature we were having.
Legoland is in my book something I would consider suggesting to friend looking for kids attraction around London. 
Legoland is specially well suited for the smaller kids 4-6 of age. We visited two days and still haven't done all the small kids activities.